# Google Maps API Multiple Marker InfoWindowContent showing same data

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have consoled the data and it is fine, I see the different names being consoled properly. the multiple markers are also being created but on the InfoWindow it is only showing the data for the last row for every Marker.

```
<?php

  include 'connect.php';

  $locations=array();
  $apikey = "APIKEY";
  $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM fields');
  while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ){

            $name = $row['field_name'];
            $longitude = $row['field_longitude'];                              
            $latitude = $row['field_latitude'];
            $owner = $row['field_owner'];
            $incharge = $row['field_incharge_name'];
            $contact_number = $row['contact_number'];
            $field_address = $row['field_address'];
            $field_pitch_length = $row['field_pitch_length'];
            $field_pitch_breadth = $row['field_pitch_breadth'];
            $ground_busy_hours_per_week = $row['ground_busy_hours_per_week'];
            $locations[]=array('field_name'=>$name,'lat'=>$latitude,'lng'=>$longitude, 'owner'=>$owner, 'incharge'=>$incharge, 'contact_number'=>$contact_number, 'field_address'=>$field_address, 'field_pitch_length'=>$field_pitch_length, 'field_pitch_breadth'=>$field_pitch_breadth, 'ground_busy_hours_per_week'=>$ground_busy_hours_per_week);
        }
        $markers = json_encode($locations);

?>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        <?php
            echo "var markers=$markers;\n";
        ?>
        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 10,
              center: {lat: 15.3489395, lng: 73.7347356},
              mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });                               

            for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker;
                infoWindowContent = '<div class="info_content">' +
                '<h4>Field Name: </h4><p>'+' '+markers[i].field_name+'</p><br>' +
                '<h4>Owner: </h4><p>'+' '+markers[i].owner+'</p><br>' +
                '<h4>Incharge: </h4><p>'+' '+markers[i].incharge+'</p><br>' +
                '<h4>Contact No: </h4><p>'+' '+markers[i].contact_number+'</p><br>' +
                '<h4>Field Address: </h4><p>'+' '+markers[i].field_address+'</p><br>' +
                '<h4>Pitch Length: </h4><p>'+' '+markers[i].field_pitch_length+'</p><br>' +
                '<h4>Pitch Breadth: </h4><p>'+' '+markers[i].$field_pitch_breadth+'</p><br>' +
                '<h4>Busy Hours per Week: </h4><p>'+' '+markers[i].ground_busy_hours_per_week+'</p><br>' +
                '</div>';
                lat = parseFloat(markers[i].lat);
                lng = parseFloat(markers[i].lng);
              var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map
              });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker));
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
        }   


    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
```

Sorry cannot share the DB, maybe for testing you can use dummy data. I have no idea why it is only displaying the data from the last row.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass the "infoWindowContent" also to the closure.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infoWindowContent) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, infoWindowContent));
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Something so silly I missed out on!. Thanks